# RealmResults size not returning expected value

Tags: android, realm

So I have some code that, upon completion of an action in the app, some data is saved to realm. I use the following code for this:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Copying to realm...");
                realm.copyToRealm(mPlayLog);
            }
        });

        RealmResults<PlayLog> res = realm.where(PlayLog.class).findAll();
        Log.d(TAG, "Size after saving: " + res.size());
```

After saving, the appropriate "Size after saving:" is printed.

I then have a scheduled task that runs every minute or so, to push this data to an api.

In the tasks code, I query Realm for the previously saved data, using the following:

```
myRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            RealmResults<PlayLog> playLogResults = myRealm.where(PlayLog.class).findAll();

            int size = playLogResults.size();

            Log.d("done", "results: " + size);
```

Heres the issue, after this code runs, results is 0. Why is it not finding the data?

Comment: Do the two snippets run in two different threads? Are these threads Looper threads?

Comment: They both are in the main thread: http://prntscr.com/blu9s8 One of them is in a `Service` and one is in a `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Try to do `myRealm.waitForChange()` just before `myRealm.where()...`

Comment: That would block the main thread..cant wait for changes inside a looper thread.

Comment: If you are in a Looper thread, the Realm is updated. From your indentation, I have a feeling that you are leaving out some code. And it might be that code which causes troubles. Please update so we can get a better picture of what is going on.

Comment: @geisshirt As far as I can tell this is all relevant code. My project consists of an app module and sdk module. My app module depends on my sdk module. When a method is called in the sdk, I record it and save it to realm in a `Service`. Then every X minutes, an AlarmManager fires off to a `BroadcastReceiver` which should then extract the record from realm, and save it to a rest api. https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3079 for more details.